# How to connect different questions in forms to one column in the responses

Tags: google-forms

I created a form to take the attendance of my students and created one page for each class and one main page that has all the grades that enables me to move to the other pages. The responses sheet has all the questions in separate columns. What I need is to make e.g. "name question" from the different pages appear in one column in the responses and the grades as well to show in one column.

I hope I explained what I need well.

I created one page with grades list that takes me to different pages with the names of the students and their attendance. When I checked the responses, I found out that all the questions are exported into that sheet. So I have a column for grade 1 and a column for the name and a column for the attendance. And the same thing with the other grades. Is there any way or an add on to take the attendance or any other way to make the answers for the grades to show in one column and the same thing with the other questions.

Answer (score 3):

The form will always record responses to separate questions in separate columns. But you can add a column with a formula that joins them together. For example, if you enter `=join(", ", B2:K2)` in cell L2 and drag down the column, the column L will have the data from columns B-K, separated by commas for readability.

A more complex example is `=B2&" "&C2&": "&join(", ", D2:K2)` which turns a row such as

```
 | 2/7/2016 | Jane |  Doe  |  3  |  1  |  4  |  1  |  5  |  9  |  2  |
```

into the string `Jane Doe: 3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9, 2`.